# Python How to convert Series type : object to int

Tags: python, string, pandas, int, jupyter

I'm trying to convert a Series object to integer. But I'm having trouble doing it. Every time I try something I have a new Error.

1. I tried to convert using `pd.to_numeric`, error while parsing string `None`
2. Then I tried to replace `None` values with `NaN` : problem replacing

#1.1)

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Var1'], downcast = 'integer')
```

---

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "None" at position 44816
```

#1.2)

```
df.astype({'Var1':'int64'}).dtypes
```

---

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

#2)

```
df['Var1'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

---

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

actual result: dtype: `object`
expected result: dtype: `int64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import numpy as np
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a string `"None"` in one (or more) of the cells. Try to first replace it with `np.nan` and then cast to numeric:

```py
import numpy as np
df = df.replace("None", np.nan).astype({'Var1': float})
```

Note that in pandas version <0.24 you can't have missing values (NaNs) in an integer column, that's why I suggested casting it to float.