# Converting floats to int not working when using a function

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I have a column in a dataframe that I need to join on. The column contains mixed data types, eg:

```
s = pd.Series([3985500,'3985500',3985500.0,'3985500.0','3985500A','3985500B'])
```

I'm trying to convert everything that's numeric to int to ensure the key is found when joining. Whatever is string can remain string and the final column format is allowed to be string, as long as the floats are converted to int.

I have tried `astype()`, but it ignores floats and for some reason I keep on getting scientific notation (see index 2 and 3):

```
s.astype(int, errors='ignore')

0       3985500
1       3985500
2    3.9855e+06
3     3985500.0
4      3985500A
5      3985500B
dtype: object
```

I get `pd.to_numeric` to work on floats with a `try-except`:

```
try: int(pd.to_numeric(s[3]))
except ValueError: s[3]

3985500
dtype: int
```

However, as soon as I try it in a function it returns nothing:

```
def convert_to_int(cell):
  try: int(pd.to_numeric(cell))
  except ValueError: cell

convert_to_int(s[3])
```

Any idea why this is happening? There might be other workarounds, but why is it not working when it's in a function?

I wish to use this function with `s.apply()`. I have looked at a couple of similar posts:

- [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)
- [Python How to convert Series type : object to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161836/python-how-to-convert-series-type-object-to-int)

Comment: `return int(pd.to_numeric(cell))`. Also, you can probably pass `downcast` argument as "integer" to `to_numeric` and avoid having to use `int` to cast.

Comment: Do you run this in a notebook? Your bare try-except should not produce output either, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @lightalchemist, the return is exactly what was missing. See the accepted answer. However, using the downcast option still returns the value at index 2 as a float for some reason.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes I'm running this in a notebook which is why it was displaying a result in the bare `try-except`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any value from your function i.e,

```
def convert_to_int(cell):
  try: 
      return int(pd.to_numeric(cell))
  except ValueError: 
      cell

convert_to_int(s[3])
```

And to use apply() syntax:

```
s.apply(lambda x:convert_to_int(x))
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a rookie mistake. I assumed the return is implied as it was displaying a value in Google Colab without the return when it's without the function. But it makes sense as it was not a function yet. I accepted this as the correct answer as it answers the question on why it's not working as a function. The answer by @MayankPorwal seems more efficient though.

Comment: Btw, the `except` also needs a return if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert all numeric type values into `int`. You don't need to have a separate function, you can simply use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), like this:

```
In [202]: s = pd.Series([3985500,'3985500',3985500.0,'3985500.0','3985500A','3985500B'])
In [203]: s = s.apply(lambda x:x if isinstance(x, str) else int(x)) 

In [204]: s
Out[204]: 
0      3985500
1      3985500
2      3985500
3    3985500.0
4     3985500A
5     3985500B
dtype: object
```

The above command converts all numeric types to `int`, keeping `string` as it is.

Comment: Thanks, but this method still returns the number at index 3 as a float. It seems more efficient though.

Comment: It returns a float at index 3 because, it us defined as a string while initializing `s`.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's why I went with the `try-except`, to first try and convert to int. How would you make provision for the string at index 3?